# LINQ Query for File Types, Size, and Count

Tags: c#, linq, file

I am currently trying to make a method that will create a query in C# LINQ that will give me the file type, the combined size of the file type, and the total amount of files of that type. I am struggling to get multiple columns and to have the query gather the file size. It seems to only work if I get the file size separately, but still can't seem to sum them up....

This one works getting the file size alone:

```
    var size = from f in files
               select (new FileInfo(f).Length);
```

but does not work here and I can't get the file count either:

```
        var all = from f in files
                  
                  group Path.GetExtension(f) by Path.GetExtension(f).ToLower() into fileGroup
                  select new {
                    Ext = fileGroup,
                    Byt = new FileInfo(fileGroup).Length
                  };
```

EDIT:

I was able to group by type & count, but still can't figure out how to add up the file sizes by their type:

```
    var info = files.Select(f => Path.GetExtension(f).ToLower()).GroupBy(x => x, (t, c) => new {
                                                                                                Extension = t,
                                                                                                Count = c.Count(),
                                                                                                Size = new FileInfo(x).Length
```

I am getting an error for the x

Comment: First, did you try to solve your question you made 1 hour ago? First close that question, eventualy ask additive information (we still can edit our answers) before creating a new one that is almost the same one.

Comment: @Siegfried.V Apologies, I have updated the last post and this post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'm going to recommend you rename the method parameter to `filePaths`, because they are strings representing the paths. When you deal with a `FileInfo` object, that's better described as a "file".

---

You got close with the group by, the important thing is that the select afterwards is acting on the group's data.

I'm going to write this with extension methods.

```
var fileDataByExtension = filePaths
    .Select(fp => new FileInfo(fp))
    .GroupBy(f => f.Extension)
    .Select(group => new
    {
        Extension = group.Key,
        TotalBytes = group.Sum(f => f.Length),
        TotalFiles = group.Count()
    });
```

1. Start with your collection of strings (`filePaths`)
2. Turn all your strings into `FileInfo` objects up-front. It's a lot easier to extract the extension and size information from it.
3. Group by the extension
4. For each group (extension)

   - the Key is the extension (.txt, .exe, etc)
   - Sum up all the group's Lengths (the size of each file)
   - Count up all the group's entries

You now have an IEnumerable of anonymous objects.

Comment: thank you @gunr2171 for this! It really helped!!
Do you happen to know how I can convert it to an XDocument? I am now stuck on that part. I tried `XDocument x = new XDocument(fileDataByExtension)` but I get an error stating "Non-Whitespace characters cannot be added to content"

Comment: That will be your next question. Make sure to give it a day or so to really do your own research and try things out first.

Answer (score -1):

So "files" should be enumerable that has a count or size that contains the number of files.

```
 var size = from f in files
          select (new FileInfo(f).Length);
```